# Base query to work even if parameters not supplied

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a search with multiples parameters. Some of them optional.
In this example i am only using two, for effect of simplicity.

If the `industry_id` is `None` i will have this error:

```
invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 3: WHERE companies_company.industry_id = ''
```

---

```
pagination = Company.query.filter((Company.industry_id == industry_id) & (Company.size == size)).paginate(
                page, per_page=current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'],
                error_out=False)
```

My question is, i need to have multiples if else with all the possible combinations? In this case, a filter with:

```
if not size:
   Company.query.filter((Company.industry_id == industry_id
elif not industry_id:
   Company.query.filter((Company.size == size
else:
   Company.query.filter((Company.industry_id == industry_id & Company.size == size
    ...
```

This is horrible to maintain because i have more than 2 options and this implies many combinations of if and elses. Any alternative to keep a base query to work even if a element of filter is none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to built your entire query in one line. You can build it as you go.

```
query = Company.query
if size:
    query = query.filter(Company.size == size)
if industry_id:
    query = query.filter(Company.industry_id == industry_id)
result = query.all()
```

If you feel like this is too verbose, you could build a list of filters and then pass them all to `filter()`.

```
filters = []
if size:
    filters.append(Company.size == size)
if industry_id:
    filters.append(Company.industry_id == industry_id)
result = Company.query.filter(*filters).all()
```

To reduce your typing even further, depending on how you obtain values `size` and `industry_id`, you could use a list comprehension.

```
fields = ('size', 'industry_id')
filters = [getattr(Company, field) == request.form.get(field) for field in fields]
result = Company.query.filter(*filters).all()
```